# How to fix this code so that it prints a string of letters with one of the positions replaced by a corresponding inputted number?

Tags: python, string

### Question:

Create a function replaceCharAtPos(orig,pos)  that receives two input parameters,  a string (orig)  and a positive integer number (pos).

If the number is a position within the string, the function should return a new string. The new string should be the original string except that instead of the original character in that position pos, it should have the position number itself (if the position number has more than 1 digit, the character should be replaced by the digit in the units part of the position number, e.g. 2 if the position number is 12).

If the number pos is not a valid position within the original string orig, the string returned should be exactly  the same as the original string.

Example of what should be inputted and outputted:

```
print (replaceCharAtPos("abcd",2))
```

This gives the output ab2d, because the number 2 corresponds the index position 2 of the string (index starts at 0) so it replaces "c" of "abcd"

### Problem with my code:

```
def replaceCharAtPos(orig,pos):
    if pos >= (len(orig)):
        return orig
    orig = list(orig)
    orig[pos] = str(pos)
    return ''.join(orig)
```

When putting a two digit number, such as 12, the new string should take the second/LAST digit of 12 which is 2. Look below to see my problem with my code:

```
print (replaceCharAtPos('abcdefghijklmn',12))
```

The output I get is `abcdefghijkl12n`, but it is supposed to be `abcdefghijkl2n`. How to fix this? I've tried changing `str(pos)` to `str(pos[-1])` but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: The modulo operator `%` helps here

Comment: How to use %? If I add that in my code it will change the rest of the conditions and only satisfy that condition of digits containing more than one digit. For example, my code works for one digit, digits that are greater than the length of the string itself, but not for two digit numbers, like I showed in my problem

Comment: For an integer `n` what is the result of `n % 10`?

Comment: % gives the remainder. How to incorporate it in my code? Is it necessary? because my code works for everything except for this condition

Comment: And when dividing by 10 this remainder is the same as?

Comment: im confused what are you dividing 10 by? what is the value of n? I know n represents an integer but the remainder will be different when dividing 10 by a different number say like 76 or 10

Comment: 10/10 gives remainder of 0 and for other numbers the remainder will be different. so this is not uniform for all conditions

Comment: It wasn't meant for a condition.

Comment: Examples: `76 % 10 == 6`, `12 % 10 == 2`, `2 % 10 == 2`, `23 % 10 == 3`

Comment: aside from this method, why won't changing str(pos) to str(pos[-1]) work? It totally makes sense that it will work ,but keeps showing an error

Comment: ohhhhhh it gives the second digit because anything multiplied by 10 will always contain the first number followed by a 0

Comment: `pos` is an integer which isn't seen as a sequence for which you can select a part. You must first convert it to a string (sequence of characters) and then ask for the last character.

Comment: Still confused on where to put the '%' in my code

Comment: so like this? first assign a variable to this string, new_string = str(pos[-1]) and then change str(pos) to new_string? I think I've tried this before, it still didnt work

Comment: No. First convert to string `str(pos)`, then select last character: `str(pos)[-1]`. For the modulo variant you must first calculate the remainder and then convert it to string: `str(pos % 10)`.

Comment: Which lines in my code do  I make this change? I'm assuming the last two. So change it to this? orig[pos] = str(pos) to orig[pos] = str(pos % 10) then finally return?

Comment: Only the `str(pos)` in the second to last line.

Comment: Thank you it worked now. Just to fully understand this problem, I know you mentioned it, but how does str(pos % 10) differ from str(pos[-1]), they look nearly identical. is it because pos is a integer, not a string, so the [n] will not work because [n] only works for strings?

Comment: Right. Depending on datatype (string, integer, ...) only some operations are allowed, some have different meanings. E.g. the `%` operator on strings is allowed but has a completely different function (text formatting) as on numbers.

Comment: @Patrick. Let's say `x = 15`. Clearly, `x % 10` results in `5`. But what is `x[-1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `[-1]` index in the converted index from the argument to ensure it always take the last digit if more than 1 digit supplied. You almost got it correct, but the way you did `str(pos[-1])` is you tried to slice the `pos` which is an `integer` as opposed to the converted `str`.

```
In [10]: def replace_char_at_idx(orig, idx): 
    ...:     if idx >= (len(orig)): 
    ...:         return orig 
    ...:     orig = list(orig) 
    ...:     # Take always the last digit from the CONVERTED 
    ...:     orig[idx] = str(idx)[-1] 
    ...:     return ''.join(orig) 


In [11]: replace_char_at_idx("abcdefghijklmn", 12)                                                                                                                                                                
Out[11]: 'abcdefghijkl2n'
```